# Why can't i install my newly created CocoaPod?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I created a framework and wanted to distribute it via CocoaPods. For that I published the code to CocoaPod's Specs github repository (https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git) using the command:

```rb
pod trunk push RXSStoryblokClient.podspec
```

The pod was successfully pushed to the trunk (https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/commit/b0a141b3c741d757090f61d1579ec92a7c0ebfb6) and on the outside everything seems to have worked. But when I create a small test project and try to install the newly created pod by adding it to the podfile and running

```rb
pod install
```

it tells me: `Unable to find a specification for 'RXSStoryblokClient'`

I have tried (as suggested by cocoapods) to update the repo using the

```rb
pod repo update
```

command, but this didn't resolve the issue.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually resolved itself. It seems CocoaPods had not finished some indexing work and 48h after pushing the pod spec to github, the installation finally worked.